# Should we use Voters or ACL? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both? Any pitfalls?

Tags: security, symfony, permissions, acl, roles

We are building an application to manage internships (for example “Internship 2nd master Medicine”). The application is being built in Symfony2.
We have users that can have one or more roles (for example a coach can also be a supervisor). 
Roles used in the examples below are:

- Student (obvious)
- Administrator (manages internships)
- Supervisor (mentor of the student in a company)
- Coach (coaches a group of students in a certain internship)

The roles are not limited to the ones mentioned above.

Some examples of what kind of permissions we have:

- Occasionally it is as easy as: all users with role “Administrator” can access a certain page. But in 99% of the cases it is not as simple as this.
- All users can view glossary items, but only those items that are linked to a faculty where the user is linked to in some way. A student for example is linked to an internship which is linked to a certain faculty. A supervisor is linked to an internship in the same way. A user with the “Administrator” role is faculty coordinator for a certain faculty only. So there are a whole bunch of rules which decide if a user is linked to one or more faculties.
- A student can give his preferences for an internship where he/she is linked to, but only if there are preferences to be given for that internship, and between certain specified dates for that internship.
- A supervisor can mail students, but only those students assigned to him/her.
- A coach can see details of students, but only of those students he/she is coach for. It is the administrator that has the rights to assign students to a coach.
- …

As you can see the permission system is not only limited to users having certain roles, and a role having certain permissions to entities. Sometimes it is somewhat more complex, the permissions are limited to a subset of data.
Notice we will have each year about 5000 students and 4000 supervisors using the application. The student database will each year grow with 1000+.

My question: should we use Voters, ACL, a combination of the two, …? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Are there any pitfalls?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use voters. The ACL component [has been extracted from Symfony core](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14718) (Symfony 2.8/3.0) because it is not actively maintained and is (too) complex.

Everything is doable with voters and it's now the recommended way for new projects.

Comment: also, not that since 2.6, voters have gotten much easier to implement: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-simpler-security-voters

Answer (score 1):

ACL is too complex and like Kévin stated it's gonna be out of symfony core. Voters is the way to go, much simpler and powerful enough.